# How to integrate $\frac{\cos(x)}{e^x}$?

Tags: integration

Surprisingly I haven't found such integral in the web, so I may ask this here bluntly.

A solution that **Matlab** suggest sounds like $\frac{{\mathrm{e}}^{-x}\,\left(\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{2}$

Comment: Integration by parts (twice) & rearrange. Alternatively differentiate the antiderivative that CAS gives you.

Comment: I found this  https://doubtnut.com/question-answer/if-ln-int-emx-cosn-x-dx-then-prove-that-m2-n2inem-xmcosx-nsinxcosn-1x-nn-1ln-2-1432779, just put $m=-1,n=1$

Comment: Let $Re(x)$ denote the real part of $x$, $i$ - imaginary unit. Then the sought integral is equal to $\int Re(e^{ix})e^{-x}dx$. Clearly this is $Re(\int e^{x(i-1)}dx)=Re(e^{(i-1)x}/(i-1))=e^{-x}Re(e^{ix}(i+1)/(i^2-1))$. Now the real part is clear. Plus the constant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int {e^{-x}} \cos x dx \\ = -e^{-x} \cos x -\int e^{-x} \sin x dx \\ =-e^{-x}\cos x +e^{-x}\sin x -\int e^{-x}\cos x dx $$

Move the integral to the other side and divide by $2$:

$$\int e^{-x}\cos x dx = \frac{e^{-x}}{2} (\sin x -\cos x) + \text{constant}$$

Comment: The solution that Matlab suggested was wrong because it was dealing with $\int e^{-2\,x}\, \cos(x) \mathrm{d}x$. Thanks to your approach I could retrace it to the proper solution  $ -\frac{{\mathrm{e}}^{-2\,x}\,\left(2\,\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{5}$

Comment: @Leon Great. ${}$

Answer (score 4):

Just rewrite it as

\begin{equation*}
\int e^{-x} \cos x \ \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
and integrate by parts.
That should lead you to your solution.

Answer (score 4):

I think the integrate-by-parts answers are best.  The alternative is to use complex numbers as rrv suggests:
$$
\frac{\cos x}{e^x} = \text{Re }e^{ix-x} = \text{Re }e^{(i-1)x}
$$
then
$$
\int e^{(i-1)x}dx = \frac{e^{(i-1)x}}{i-1} +C
\\
\int \frac{\cos x}{e^x}\;dx = \text{Re }\frac{e^{(i-1)x}}{i-1}+C
= \frac{e^{-x}}{2}(\sin(x)-\cos(x)) +C
$$

Answer (score 3):

In general, $\int e^{-x}[f’(x)-f(x)]dx= e^{-x}f(x)$.
Then
$$\int e^{-x}(\cos x-\sin x)dx= e^{-x}\sin x,\>\>\>\>\>
 \int e^{-x}(\cos x+\sin x)dx= -e^{-x}\cos x
$$
Add them to obtain
$$\int e^{-x}\cos x dx = \frac12e^{-x}(\sin x -\cos x) + C$$

Answer (score 2):

$$I=\int\frac{\cos x}{e^x}dx=\int e^{-x}\cos(x)dx=\Re\int e^{-(1-i)x}dx=\Re\left(-\frac{e^{-(1-i)x}}{(1-i)}\right)=\Re\left(-\frac{(1+i)}{2}e^{-x}(\cos x+i\sin x)\right)$$
$$=-\frac{e^{-x}}2\Re\left[\cos x-\sin x+i\cos x+i\sin x\right]=\frac{e^{-x}\left(\sin x-\cos x\right)}{2}+C$$